# Why can we substitute any arbitrary variable in for this expression of the CDF?

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to follow this example of a variable transformation, which defines the PDF and CDF as follows:

[image: pdf and cdf definitions]
**PROBLEM**: The above definition is used in solving this problem:
[image: remark]
[image: problem]
[image: variable transformation]

**Question**: Now, where I get confused is why we are allowed to differentiate $F_X(x_1)$ to get $f_Y(y)$?  I would have thought for sure that by the definition we would need to differentiate $F_Y(y)$ in order to get $f_Y(y)$.  Why are we allowed to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should differentiate $F_Y(y)$, and just before that statement they showed $F_Y(y) = F_X(g^{-1}(y))$.